# UITextView With "See More" Button if it doesn't fit inside UITableViewCell IOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, tableview

It sounds so simple but it's not, what I want is to make a UITableViewCell with a UITextView inside. I am using auto layout so when the tableview first loads all cell they will all be in the same maximum static size and when I press the cell the cell expand according to the UITextView's text.
The hard part is to add a "See More" button in the end of the text view if it doesn't fit the static size.(before the cell was pressed)

I also saved to array if the cell was pressed to know if to expand it or not.
another tricky part is if the textview is below the static size than use the UITableViewAutomaticDimension so if its 40 points of height I don't want the cell to be 102 point because of a blank space the will be created
for that I need to know if the textview is below 102 point.
I thought about implementing heightForRow something like that

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if([self isCellWithIndexNeedsToExpand:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]])
        {
            return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        }
        else
        {
            int height = [self someFunctionThatGivesTheTextViewHeight];
            if(height>102)
                return 102;
            else
               return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In autolayout it does not matter at all.. but through code you can use this below code to find estimated string size,

```
CGSize labelSize = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont:myLabel.font 
                            constrainedToSize:myLabel.frame.size 
                                lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

CGFloat labelHeight = labelSize.height;
```

then you can increase the height of row

Comment: the problem with your answer is that i cant do this calculation inside heightForRow method because the label has not been created yet, it will be created in cellForRow

Comment: ya but you have the array which have the string what you are actually going to pass to the label.text. right? you can find the estimated height from this. can you catch my point. i already did this like "see more".

Comment: For example we have array which have the collection of strings. Exactly we need "see more" content for this string right? so you have to call estimated height for this string , from this you can move further.

Comment: i can get the text, but not the label width, because in different screen size the width will be different which means the height will also be different, beside that, do you know a nice gitHub project for textview with see more button?

Comment: Sorry friend i could not find any useful project for this. Let me check once again

Comment: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html    see the link friend which based on autolayout . Did you little bit interest in autolayout please consider this

Comment: Cool my friend... All the best.